# oracle utl_mail message body size limit

Tags: oracle, email, varchar2

I am using the utl_mail procedure in oracle 10.x and have noticed that if I try to pass a value with a length of more than 4000 characters into the varchar2 input for Message, I get an error: 4000 works, 4001 fails.  Is this a hard-coded limit, or is there a setting somewhere that I can change to increase this?  I would have thought it would be 32000 limit...

thanks for any and all help
mike

Answer (score 5):

[UTL_MAIL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm#i1000954) is a simple wrapper over UTL_SMTP, it's only generally used for short simple emails.

```
UTL_MAIL.SEND (
   sender      IN    VARCHAR2,
   recipients  IN    VARCHAR2,
   cc          IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   bcc         IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   subject     IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   message     IN    VARCHAR2,
   mime_type   IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii',
   priority    IN    PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL);
```

If you use [UTL_SMTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#CHDHHBJD) instead, you can send emails of arbitrary length, by repeated calls to UTL_SMTP.DATA.

Answer (score 1):

varchar2 is limited to 4000

Comment: in `SQL`, in `PL/SQL` it's 32k